# Trying to get specific row values from Monday.com using GraphQL

Tags: graphql, monday.com

Trying to use this API to get column values for my board in GraphQL, I have a column named "Email" with the persons email address but I can't seem to query it - here is my query thus far.

```
query {
boards (ids: 341236641) {
    items () {
        id
        name
        column_values {
            id
        }
    }
}
}
```

For some reason, it wont let me put the field "Email" underneath the `items()` or `column_values`

When I look at the output, the `id` of `column_values` prints out as

`'column_values': [{'id': 'status'}, {'id': 'status84'}, {'id': 'average_check4'}, {'id': 'date'}, {'id': 'text9'}, {'id': 'location'}]}`

I believe the "actual" column name is `text9` but that doesnt seem to work either.

Anyone use this API successfully before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i'm a developer at monday.com :)

The column_values fields returns a list of ColumnValue type object. In addition to the **id** (column ID) you've fetched for each, you could also ask for **value** (the json data of this cell), **text** (the textual representation of the value), **title** (The column's title) and **additional_info**.

Try:

```
query {
  boards (ids: 341236641) {
    items () {
      id
      name
      column_values {
        id
        title
        value
        text
        additional_info
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tal! Would suggest adding this example to your docs, makes it a lot more straightforward. I guess now its here for anyone who needs it :) Thanks again